# What is the VB statement phrase "Chr(0)" equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

What is the VB statement expression `Chr(0)` equivalent in C#?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Even in VB6, `Chr(0)` is not the best option, you should use the `vbNullChar` constant as it doesn't require runtime evaluation.

Answer (score 14):

The equivalent I believe is `'\0'`

I deleted the comment as I thought it is more appropriate to update in the post :)

```
sValue = vValue + Chr(0) 'As mentioned in your comment
```

can be written as

```
sValue += "\0";
```

Comment: That's ok :) Deleted the comment and Updated the post above.

Comment: @MarkJ: That is not my code. It was given in the comment as an example by OP.

Comment: OK. So you're referring to a comment that was deleted before I looked at this question? That's confusing. How were we supposed to know that the `==` came from the OP? Maybe you could edit that into your answer

Comment: (+1 BTW) Worth mentioning that this is correct for values from 0-127. VB6 [Chr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262692(v=vs.60).aspx) uses ANSI character codes from the current system code page, not Unicode character codes. Means that none of the alternatives in your answer would be correct for other values. You would need to import Microsoft.VisualBasic and use [Chr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `(char)0`. Or `'\0'` of course. If you want to call a method, you can use `Convert.ToChar(0)`.

Comment: +1 Worth mentioning that this is correct for values from 0-127. VB6 [Chr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262692(v=vs.60).aspx) uses ANSI character codes from the current system code page, not Unicode character codes. Means that none of the alternatives in your answer would be correct for other values. VB6 has a ChrW function that accepts Unicode character codes.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent would be (char)0 . If you are looking for escape sequences and other characters you can use \n and likewise

Answer (score -2):

```
sValue == vValue + Strings.Chr(0)
```

You can try this yourself using [this website](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)